# single signon support for mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm attempting to support single signon in a system that includes MediaWiki.  I have a universal cookie that can be used to make a remote call to get logged in user information, but I'm struggling with MediaWiki's documentation/code base to see where I might plug in my 'check'.  Since php doesn't have a 'servlet filter' concept per se, I need to embed something into the mediawiki page that will make the call and set up $wgUser.

Does anyone have any experience of where I might do that? There must be some plug points I can tap into (templates somehow?), but my php is too weak to ferret it out in the mediawiki code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an [AuthPlugin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/AuthPlugin).  You'll do this by defining a new class that extends the AuthPlugin class.  In your LocalsSettings.php file, tell MediaWiki to use your AuthPlugin by setting `$wgAuth` equal to a new instance of that new class.  You'll probably use some hooks such as [UserLoadFromSession](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/UserLoadFromSession), too.

You might find it easier to review a preexisting Single Sign-on extension to see how it operates.  One example is the [QISSingleSignOn](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aQISSingleSignOn) extension.